# Get the remaining dates of current week using java

Tags: java, date

I am using the following code to get the current date and the next dates.

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList();
int nextWeekId=2;
int currentWeekId=1;

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (i >= 7) {
        saveDetails(nextWeekId,list.get(i), java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate.plusDays(i)));
    } else {
        saveDetails(currentWeekId, list.get(i), java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate.plusDays(i)));
    }
}
```

My `list` size will always the `size = 14`.  The week should always start on `Monday`. I want that if for example today is `Friday` and date is `2020-07-10`. Then my system will store the date  `2020-07-10 , 2020-07-11 , 2020-07-12` against `currentWeekId` and the complete next seven days against `nextWeekId`.
The order of accessing the values doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW… No need to use the terrible `java.sql.Date` class. As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. See setObject and getObject methods on PreparedStatement and ResultSet.

Comment: what is with the remaining 4 days of your example? id = 3?

Comment: @Eritrean no, id will be just 1 and 2. The remaining ones will be discarded.

Comment: I would consider using a `WeekFIelds` object, either `WeekFields.ISO` or for example `WeekFields.of(Locale.UK)`. (those two objects are equal, BTW).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the remaining days of the current week, you need to iterate from the current date until the next Monday as shown below:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate firstDayOfNextWeek = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        while (localDate.isBefore(firstDayOfNextWeek)) {
            System.out.println(localDate);
            localDate = localDate.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-11
2020-07-12
```

Note that [`LocalDate#with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) returns a copy of the target object with one element changed; this is the immutable equivalent to a `set` method on a JavaBean.

**[Update]:** Given below is another way (Cortesy: [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque)) to do it:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate firstDayOfNextWeek = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        List<LocalDate> remainingDays = localDate.datesUntil(firstDayOfNextWeek)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(remainingDays);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2020-07-11, 2020-07-12]
```

Check [`LocalDate#datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)) to learn more about it.

**[Another update]**

Posting this update to help OP list all days of the next week:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

        // Remaining days of the current week
        LocalDate firstDayOfNextWeek = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        List<LocalDate> remainingDays = localDate.datesUntil(firstDayOfNextWeek).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(remainingDays);

        // Days of next week
        LocalDate firstDayOfNextToNextWeek = firstDayOfNextWeek.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        List<LocalDate> daysOfNextWeek = firstDayOfNextWeek.datesUntil(firstDayOfNextToNextWeek)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(daysOfNextWeek);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2020-07-11, 2020-07-12]
[2020-07-13, 2020-07-14, 2020-07-15, 2020-07-16, 2020-07-17, 2020-07-18, 2020-07-19]
```

Comment: @Arvind Sir how could it map with my solution?

Comment: @Lily Your Question is not at all clear about the specifics. This Answer points you in the right direction, showing how to get a sequence of dates by using a `TemporalAdjuster`. You need to either edit your Question for clarity, or apply the concepts shown here to devise your own solution.

Comment: @Lily - Do you also want to create another list apart from the list created in this answer? I'll be able to help you if you clarify exactly what else you need.

Comment: For the current week your code is perfect. But I also want to `saveDetails` of next 7 dates .

Comment: @Lily - I've posted an update. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Check what day of week the start date is and then loop from that day to Sunday

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 10);
List<LocalDate> thisWeek = new ArrayList<>();

int dayCount = 0;
for (int i = date.getDayOfWeek().getValue(); i <= DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue(); i++) {
    thisWeek.add(date.plusDays(dayCount++));
}
```

To use this solution for saving the dates as in the question it would look something like this

```
int dayCount = 0;
for (int i = date.getDayOfWeek().getValue(); i <= DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue(); i++) {
    saveDetails(currentWeekId,list.get(dayCount), date.plusDays(dayCount++));
}
for (DayOfWeek day : DayOfWeek.values()) {
    saveDetails(nextWeekId,list.get(dayCount), date.plusDays(dayCount++));
}
```

Comment: Sir how could it map with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

List<LocalDate> dates = localDate
           .datesUntil(localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
System.out.println(dates);
```

Prints

```
[2020-07-11, 2020-07-12]
```

Answer (score 1):

You try this way

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
// Current week dates
LocalDate nextWeekStart = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
List<LocalDate> currentWeekdays = localDate.datesUntil(nextWeekStart).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Next week dates
LocalDate nextWeekStart2 = nextWeekStart.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
List<LocalDate> nextWeekdays = nextWeekStart.datesUntil(nextWeekStart2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //curent day
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

    // find name of the day
    String dayOfWeek = localDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , Locale.US);

    // set a week distance from current day
    LocalDate deadlineDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);

    // add dates to a list from current day to a week distance 
    List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(localDate, date -> date.plusDays(7))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(localDate, deadlineDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(dates.size() + " days to finish the order starting from " + dayOfWeek);  // 7 days to finish the order starting from Sat


    System.out.println(dates);  // [2020-07-11, 2020-07-18, 2020-07-25, 2020-08-01, 2020-08-08, 2020-08-15, 2020-08-22]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getWeek` of from the code given below, for current week you need to pass 1, next week 2, next to next week 3 and so on...

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WeekDates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getWeek(1));
        System.out.println(getWeek(2));
        System.out.println(getWeek(3));
    }

    public static List<LocalDate> getWeek(int week) {
        List<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        int days = 7 - date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() + 1;
        if (week != 1) {
            date = date.plusDays((week - 2) * 7 + days);
            days = 7;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
            list.add(date);
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```